# passing a parameter to import late bind

Tags: javascript, node.js, phaser-framework

I am in the middle of building a game using Phaser.js (version 3.20.1) and I want to have this singleton class called TimeTracker which would keep track of the players time as certain event occur throughout the game.  So that any scene can call

```
 TimeTracker.AddTime(3)
```

But my TimeTracker also needs access to a UI screen to display UI messages.  Now with other objects what I have done is initialize the UI scene in the Game Controller create method

```
this.UI = this.scene.get('UI');
```

and then pass it into the constructor of other objects

```
this.tableD = new D(this.UI, this.Attributes);
this.tableF = new F(this.UI, this.Attributes);
```

But since TimeTracker is a singleton how do I write the following pseudo code?

```
import TimeTracker from '../gameObjects/TimeTracker'(this.UI);
```

Since UI doesn't exist yet.

Furthermore, as I type this, I wonder if I should go with the singleton approach or just create one instance in create and pass that around also like the UIScene

Is there a best programming practice when sharing one instance of a class across many classes (Scenes in Phaser)?

Comment: Well your TimeTracker class doesn't have a single responsibility, you should have a separate object that reads from it, and updates the UI

Comment: Trying to understand your answer -- Time Tracker keeps track of the game time as certain actions occur through out the game, battles, moving rooms, searching... so even if I create a separate class to read it and update the ui, then that class would still have to be passed everywhere -- unless I trigger it by events, maybe